# how to getstandard value from Spinner with multilanguage app on Android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I've an App where user can post photo and give some attributes to it.

Users can determine which category the photo belongs within a set of default categories, i try to show the categories options in a Spinner and the values come from a xml array compiled into the app.

This way i can show the categories in whichever language user is running the app.

The problem i have is to convert the value got from spinner back into a standard set for store in my database. Because depending of what language user set, i get the value as a different word and is a nightmare to create a converter which could handle it and translate from N different languages into my standard enum.

I would like to do something like radiobutton, like each option has a label (in whatever langague user wants) and a value (which i can define in a stardard way) so when i get selectedItemValue() i always get same value independent of language.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: by xml you mean you define different res folders and xml files according to each language and inside that you define a string array? and my second question is why don't you use the position of the selected item?

Comment: It isn't a good design to use "position" as key to anything in software development, it can easily be changed or even accidentally... i may want show the options alphabetically to the user what will change positions

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to use `res/raw/` with different qualifiers depending on your locals instead of using string array.
It helps you to store json files in them. So you can have a list of custom objects which have both title and id.
And you store id in the database, and id is the same in all locals.

Comment: it sounds a good idea, can i have `raw-en`, `raw-pt` `raw-es` like i do with `values` ?